# How to track location through GPS in android application

Tags: android, gps

I am working on development of android game application. I want to judge location of players of game. I want that details like pincode, city name,country name, geo cordinates, accuracy etc.

```
public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
Context context;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location2) {
    location2.getLatitude();
    location2.getLongitude();
    @Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    AlertPopup.displayPopup(context, "GPS Disabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    AlertPopup.displayPopup(context, "GPS Enabled");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

but not able to get all data which i want

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are aware how to use GPS in android. Here is how to get the information you want.

> **Pincode, city name, country name**

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try
        {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            }
            addressString = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        addressString = "No where";
    }
```

> **Geo cordinates, accuracy**

```
location.getLatitude()
```

and

```
location.getAccuracy()
```

Comment: it returns "no where" but i want perfect data as i mensioned in earlier post well i use command "telnet localhost <emulator port>" and  "geo fix lat lan" for check the data so how i can find that data